# Vue 3 Realoading component if variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to realod component if selectedLeague has been changed

```
<label class="label">Select league</label>
<div class="selector">
  <v-select
      v-model="selectedLeague"
      :dropdown-should-open="dropdownShouldOpen"
      :options="leagues"
      label="displayLeague"
      placeholder="Select a league"
  />
</div>

<div v-if="selectedLeague">
  <LeagueTopScorers :is="selectedLeague" :selectedLeague="selectedLeague.id.toString()" />
</div>
```

In LeagueTopScorers component I am fetching API to get top scorers from selected league.

I tried :watch, v-on:, created()

Comment: Are you trying to fetch and display new data after selection? Because a true component reload will not keep the selection, it will revert to the default before the selection. Also, your use of `:is` is not correct syntax.

Comment: I am trying to pass a new variable prop to my component which should fetch data and display it in my parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<LeagueTopScorers />` ***does*** re-render when `selectedLeague` changes <sup>***1***</sup>, but it doesn't re-mount.
It only mounts when `selectedLeague` changes from a *falsy* value to a *truthy* one (because that's when the value of the `v-if` changes).

There are a few problems with your question:

- you're asking about a technical aspect (let's call it X), which you think will solve a business requirement (let's call it Y). It's a classical XY problem. Why don't you describe the Y requirement? (e.g: what you want to achieve). What output change do you want to see on what input change?
- the code you posted is not enough to create a *runnable* example. We don't know what `v-select` is, what `<LeagueTopScorers />` is, or how does `:is` prop look like on `<LeagueTopScorers />`.

From the snippet you posted, I am guessing the following:

- `v-select` is either [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) or [Vuetify select component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/)
- you expect `:is` to work on `<LeagueTopScorers />` as it does on `<component />`. Hint: it doesn't, unless you coded it yourself, which I doubt
- last, but not least, I guess you want some code you placed into an init lifecycle hook of `<LeagueTopScorers />` (e.g: `onMounted`) to run when you replace an object stored in `selectedLeague` with another object.

If I'm correct, the simplest and cleanest way to achieve this behavior is to create a computed ***<sup>2</sup>***:

```js
const leagueId = computed(() => selectedLeague?.id.toString() || '')
```

... and use it in `v-if`, `:key` and `:selectedLeague`:

```html
<LeagueTopScorers
  v-if="leagueId"
  :selectedLeague="leagueId"
  :key="leagueId" />
```

(without the `<div v-if>` wrapper).

The above will create a new instance of `<LeagueTopScorers />` every time `leagueId` changes and will only render one when `leagueId` is not falsy. I believe that's what you were trying to accomplish, technically ***<sup>3</sup>***.

---

**Notes:**
***<sup>1</sup>*** - to verify, use `onUpdated(() => console.log('updated...'))`
***<sup>2</sup>*** - use `selectedLeague.value?.id.toString()` if `selectedLeague` is a `ref`
***<sup>3</sup>*** - at the same time, I am sure the actual business requirement can be met without creating a new instance of `<LeagueTopScorers />` every time `leagueId` changes, but I can't help more without more details and/or context

Comment: Vue select. `dropdown-should-open` is not a prop on Vuetify. Could be an error in passing props from parent to child as well, based on author comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good answer. It resovled my problem.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Consider marking it as accepted if it helped you solve the problem. If you consider it's not sufficiently relevant for your actual problem, consider adding your own, where you explain more clearly the problem was and how you fixed it, and marking that one as accepted. Ideally, your question (and the accepted answer) should help other users find a solution to a similar issue with ease.

Comment: Can you look at my bigger problem? It is similar to this but in different case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468482/multiply-v-model-props-to-vue-3-component-to-fetch-api-breakpoint